# How can I add buttons to a custom column in the taxonomy table?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, admin, forms, columns, buttons

I am working on an **issue-based publishing system** for a friend of mine. So far I have created a custom taxonomy called "Issue"; added several custom fields to the custom taxonomy (like "Issue number", "PDF URL" and "Is Published?"); and expanded the taxonomy management page with additional columns to show these custom term data.

Now I want to implement a convenient method to publish (and unpublish) the individual issues. My plan is to **add an additional custom column to the taxonomy management page which contains "Publish" and "Unpublish" buttons**. So I tried to populate the custom column with a form which contains hidden data fields and a visible submit button; basically I duplicated the functionality of the default term edit form, and put it in the table cells.

The problem is that the whole taxonomy management table is wrapped in a form, called "posts-filter", and **forms cannot be nested**. So my solution doesn't work properly.

Is there a proper solution for adding such buttons to a custom column? Any suggestions are welcomed!

An image for clarification:
http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/669/customcol.png

```
add_filter("manage_issue_custom_column", 'manage_issue_columns', 10, 3);

// The function that manages the custom columns
function manage_issue_columns($out, $column_name, $issue_id) {
    $issue = get_term($issue_id, 'issue');
switch ($column_name) {
    case 'issue_pdf_url':
        $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_term_$issue_id" );
        if ( isset( $term_meta["issue_pdf_url"] ) ){
            $out .= $term_meta["issue_pdf_url"]; 
        }   
    break;

    case 'issue_num':
        $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_term_$issue_id" );
        if ( isset( $term_meta["issue_num"] ) ){
            $out .= $term_meta["issue_num"];
        }
    break;

    //This is the column where I need to add buttons
    case 'issue_published':
        $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_term_$issue_id" );
        $term_object = get_term($issue_id, "issue");
        if ( isset( $term_meta["issue_published"] ) && $term_meta["issue_published"] == "yes" ){
            //This is the form which shows the publishing buttons; not working due to being nested in other form
            $out .= '<form name="edittag" id="edittag" method="post" action="edit-tags.php" class="">  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="editedtag" />  <input type="hidden" name="tag_ID" value="' . esc_attr($issue_id) . '" />  <input type="hidden" name="taxonomy" value="issue" />  ' . wp_original_referer_field(true, 'current') . wp_nonce_field('update-tag_' . $issue_id) . ' <input name="name" id="name" type="hidden" value="' . $term_object->name . '" />  <input name="slug" id="slug" type="hidden" value="' . $term_object->slug .'" />  <input name="description" id="description" type="hidden" value="' . $term_object->description .'" />  <input type="hidden" value="" checked="" id="term_meta[issue_published]" name="term_meta[issue_published]">  <input type="submit" value="Unpublish" class="button-primary" id="submit" name="submit"></form>';
        } else {
            $out .= '<form name="edittag" id="edittag" method="post" action="edit-tags.php" class="">  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="editedtag" />  <input type="hidden" name="tag_ID" value="' . esc_attr($issue_id) . '" />  <input type="hidden" name="taxonomy" value="issue" />  ' . wp_original_referer_field(true, 'current') . wp_nonce_field('update-tag_' . $issue_id) . ' <input name="name" id="name" type="hidden" value="' . $term_object->name . '" />  <input name="slug" id="slug" type="hidden" value="' . $term_object->slug .'" />  <input name="description" id="description" type="hidden" value="' . $term_object->description .'" />  <input type="hidden" value="yes" checked="checked" id="term_meta[issue_published]" name="term_meta[issue_published]">  <input type="submit" value="Publish" class="button-primary" id="submit" name="submit"></form>';
        }
    break;

    default:
    break;
}

return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For something like this you might consider adding an 'action'; which appear when you hover other the item.

*The following code is not complete, and hasn't been tested - but should get you on the right track.*

**Add the action**

First, to add the action link, use the `tag_row_actions` hook. (Keep in mind a function hooked onto this will be fired on *every* taxonomy, so you need to check the taxonomy).
Something like:

```
add_filter('tag_row_actions','my_term_action',10,2);
function my_term_action($actions,$tag){
if($tag->taxonomy == 'issue'):
    $actions['my-action-class'] = '<a href="#"> My action </a>';
endif;
return $actions;
}
```

The `$actions` array is associative, where the key will become the class of the `span` element that wraps the action. The value, is what the `span` will wrap around.

You can use use the `$tag` (it's an object, the term id is given by `$tag->term_id`) to determine which action to display, so if you wish to display the 'publish' action

```
$actions['my-action-class'] = '<a class="Publish" termid="'.$tag->term_id.'" href="#"> Publish </a>';
```

and if you wish to display the 'unpublish' action, instead add:

```
$actions['my-action-class'] = '<a class="Unpublish" termid="'.$tag->term_id.'" href="#"> Unpublish </a>';
```

I give them different classes and an extra attribute. This will be used by jQuery/AJAX to perform the relevant action...

**The jQuery /AJAX**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".my-action-class a").click(function(){
        change_publish_states(jQuery(this));
    });
});
    function change_publish_states(el){
   if(el.hasClass('Publish')){
      new_state = 'Unpublish';
   }else{
      new_state = 'Publish';
  }
        jQuery.getJSON(ajaxurl,
            {   term_id: el.attr("termid"),
                action: "my_change_publish_state",
                new_state: new_state
            },
            function(data) {
                if (data.error){
                    alert(data.error);                      
                }else{
                    //Update label and class
                    el.text(data.new_state);
                    el.attr('class', data.new_state)
                }
            });
    }
```

You need to add this script on the custom taxonomies page, you can run a function on `admin_enqueue_scripts` to check the page being viewed and conditionally enqueue it;

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','load_my_ajax_script');
function load_my_ajax_script(){
 //Check globals like $pagenow=='edit-tags' and $taxonomy=='issues' or $current_screen 
 //to make sure you are on the right page and enqueue script - or add a filter 
 //to print the script at the footer.

 global $current_screen;
 if ( $current_screen->id != 'edit-issue' )
  return;

 wp_enqueue_script( 'my_ajax_save', get_stylesheet_directory_URI() . '/my_ajax_save.js' );
}
```

Then it remains to add a function onto the AJAX action-hook :

**AJAX action**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_change_publish_state', 'change_the_publish_state');
function change_the_publish_state(){

   $term_id = $_GET['term_id'];
   $new_state = $_GET['new_state'];

   //Perform checks / logic & update publish status.
   $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_term_$term_id" );

   if ( $new_state == "Unpublish" )
    $term_meta['issue_published'] = 'yes';

   if ( $new_state == "Publish" )
    $term_meta['issue_published'] = '';

   update_option( "taxonomy_term_$term_id", $term_meta );    

//return the new state of the term
   $result['new_state'] = $new_state;
    echo json_encode($result);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Stephen! Your help is really appreciated. I managed to successfully implement the solution.